# Create the footer in Data Table and to Export it with its footer into Excel and PDF

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I am trying to find the total of 'Net Value' and ' Total Value' in datatable as footer  and the total value should be shown inside td element with the same alignment of its other data column. If I try to add footer , the total column shows different position from its data column also How can I find the total value and how to show it in footer row corresponding the column of its data row. Here is my code in html. Since I am not able to show the original program , I had to make it in presentable format. I am showing the data by calling JsonResult method from the controller , After fetching the data from the method and showing the report, the footer value will be showing bit far from its data column

```
@model myModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;font-size:90%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Item
                                </th>

                                <th>
                                    Net Value
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Total Value
                                </th>
                                
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="body">

                            <tr>
                                <td>Item</td>
                                <td>NetVal</td>
                                <td>TotVal</td>                              
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>                                
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var report = {};
            report.FromDate = "@Model.FromDate";
            report.ToDate = "@Model.ToDate";
            report.CustomerCode = "@Model.CustomerCode";
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/mySales/SalesData",
                    "data": report,
                    "dataSrc": function (json) {
                        console.log(json);
                        return JSON.parse(json);
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Item" },
                    { "data": "NetVal" },
                    { "data": "TotVal" },                  
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"
                    },
                    { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
                    { "width": "5%", "targets": 1 },
                    { "width": "5%", "targets": 2 },                   
                ],
                "pageLength": 40,
                scrollY: "500px",
                scrollX: true,
                paging: true,
                footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;
                    var intVal = function (i) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ?
                            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                                i : 0;
                    };

                    var col1 = api
                        .column(1)
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    var col2 = api
                        .column(2)
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    $(api.column(1).footer()).html(col1);
                    $(api.column(2).footer()).html(col1);
                    
                },
                scrollCollapse: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'csvHtml5',
                    'pdfHtml5'

                ]

            })
        })
    </script>
```

/

```
/ Controller
public JsonResult SalesData(myModel model)
        {
            DateTime fromDate = new DateTime();
            DateTime toDate = new DateTime();
            if (report.FromDate != "" && report.ToDate != "" && report.FromDate != null && report.ToDate != null)
            {
                fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(report.FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(report.ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            report.CustomerCode = "001";
            var data = _unitOfWork.GetSummary(report.CustomerCode, fromDate, toDate);
            String jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return Json(jsonResult);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try  `scrollCollapse: true` to set the footer to the right position,add  a fallbackfunction to calculate the total value ,and check this [demo](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)  related with  export button if you missed to refer the js/css files

I tried as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />






<div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;font-size:90%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Item
                </th>
                <th>
                    Net Value
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total Value
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body">
            <tr>
                <td>AAA</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BBB</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CCC</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DDD</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EEE</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FFF</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GGG</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>HHH</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>III</td>
                <td>300.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Total</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>              
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>              


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 40,
            scrollY: "500px",
            scrollX: true,
            paging: true,


            
            footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api(), data;


                var intVal = function (i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                };

                var col1 = api
                    .column(1)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                var col2 = api
                    .column(2)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                $(api.column(1).footer()).html(col1);
                // Here you can add the rows
                $(api.column(2).footer()).html(col2);
            },
            

            scrollCollapse: true,



            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'

            ]



        })
    })
</script>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ruikai, I have updated my program with more details and also I am showing  when the footer alignment would be showed in wrong position.

Comment: Do you mean even if you setted   scrollCollapse: true ,the footer still seperate from other rows?

Comment: Yes, still it does show different position of its corresponding data column.  Only the problem is showed , if I populate the data from Jason method  by calling from Javascript